# specyfing value to 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' not reflected in the request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, fetch

I am receiving an error when attempting to redirect to github api for user authorization. The error says that "Reponse to preflight request doesn't pass access control check", it references no "Access-Control-Allow_origin" header is present, however I have it added in my fetch request and I have it set to wildcard.

```
 fetch('https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=00000&scope=repo', {
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {        
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',    
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      }
    })
```

I can click in the "Network" tab and double click the request and it takes me to github to authorize my application. Not sure what else I can be missing?

Comment: Do you realize that the page you are calling has to set it.... Doing it on the client is like cutting your own key and opening up a random door.

Comment: I didnt realize that but now I know that. I am just not sure how to correctly format this fetch request to work with the github api.